# C++ Unresolved Externals because of header

Tags: c++

I  just started with C++ for some OpenGL applications and wanted to pack some monster functions into a util class so that my code remains clean. This is what I did:

1. awesomeClass.h :

   ```
   #pragma once    
   class AwesomeClass    
   {    
   public:    
       static void do_something_awesome();    
   };
   ```
2. awesomeClass.cpp :

   ```
   #include "awesomeClass.h"    
   void do_something_awesome(){    
    //...    
   }
   ```
3. main.cpp :

   ```
   #include "awesomeClass.h"    
   int main(int argc, char** argv)    
   {    
       AwesomeClass::versuchen();    
       return 0;    
   }
   ```

Output:

```
Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   \Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestEnvironmment\Debug\TestEnvironmment.exe    TestEnvironmment

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl AwesomeClass::do_something_awesome(void)" (?do_something_awesome@AwesomeClass@@SAXXZ) referenced in function _SDL_main   \Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestEnvironmment\TestEnvironmment\main.obj TestEnvironmment
```

What is wrong with that code? I mean it works when I paste everything in one file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write

```
void AwesomeClass::do_something_awesome(){... }
```

Instead of

```
void do_something_awesome(){... }
```

Otherwise the function you implement does not belong to the class.

Answer (score 3):

You should write this if you want write `do_something_awesome` in separate cpp file.

```
void AwesomeClass::do_something_awesome(){    
 //...    
}
```

Or you can use:

```
    #pragma once    
    class AwesomeClass    
    {    
    public:    
        static void do_something_awesome(){
        //code here
        }  

    };
```